# How to modify specifically a column awk?

Tags: awk

I have all the time this problem and I am looking for a long term solution:

How do you specify to awk on which column the modification will be applied?

Example:

I have a file with several columns for Ids:

```
id1 id2
toto_tata_tutu  papa_pupu_popo
tuta_totu_tatu  popu_papo_pupa
tuto_tuto_tata  popo_papa_pupu
```

If I want to modify either only column 1 or only column 2 to change the separator `_` in `\t` for example. How can I do this?

Thanks in avance!

Comment: The `sub/gsub` functions act upon `$0` by default, but you can specify other input sources too.

Comment: bonjour, ok, thanks, i'll try with gsub

Comment: @CarolineJuery, Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use 3rd (optional) argument of [`gsub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) like so, let `file.txt` content be

```
id1 id2
toto_tata_tutu  papa_pupu_popo
tuta_totu_tatu  popu_papo_pupa
tuto_tuto_tata  popo_papa_pupu
```

then

```
awk '{gsub(/_/,"T",$2);print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
id1 id2
toto_tata_tutu papaTpupuTpopo
tuta_totu_tatu popuTpapoTpupa
tuto_tuto_tata popoTpapaTpupu
```

Note: for clarity sake I use uppercase letter `T`, replace `T` using `\t` if you wish to replace `_` with TAB characters

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
awk '{gsub("_", "\t", $2)}1' input_file
```

$1 works on the 1st column, $2 on the second, $3 on the 3rd, ...
see: https://awk.js.org/?gist=e4780221a9472cbbfe4ec415e100d8c7